# How to paint a piece of wood with spray

Tags: technique, wood, design

I've tried looking arround but posts are usually about giving a piece of furniture a certain color and such.

I wanted to know if there is an accessible method for a newbie to paint (I was thinking with spray, like if it was for a graffity), a piece of wood.

My idea is to have the infinity symbol on it, but the problem is that I don't know if there is materials specially for this kind of thing.

If the wood is nice I was thinking of leaving it like that, or maybe also painting a dark background so as to highlight the symbol itself.

Is there another, maybe better, way to simply paint wood? It seems easy in my mind but when I look for tutorials everything is so complicated.

Comment: Spraycan paint? *Exactly* like they use for graffiti. You can get numerous types, intended for craft projects and other jobs around the house, for car touch-up spraying (from stores selling automotive supplies) and now there are specialist cans made for graffiti artists to use (sold in art shops usually). The problem is any of these can do what you want but you need the control to be able to paint the shapes you want neatly, and that can only come with practice.

Comment: Ey graphus, thanks for taking the time to answer!! Means a lot for someone as clueless as me. About the practice, I was actually thinking about... I duno how is it called, but basically using a template so I just have to spray over and get the symbol or whatever, it seemed like a solution to my lack of experience, what do you think? What you said about how there are numerous types is so true, and so confusing for me, but it does seem like there are several that can do the job just fine... So I will look for the types you mentioned.

Comment: Templates or masks work well for spraying, but the edges can look a bit ugly once the mask is removed.

Comment: @keont: The template is called a [stencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil). You can buy them or make your own out of thin plastic (or other materials).